# Value in variable is not updated in label tag

Tags: javascript, html

i have a small problem in my code when i try to update the value in the variable "a" to class attribute of label tag. Can anyone help me out. here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
label.visible {visibility:visible}
label.hidden {visibility:hidden}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a;
function doset()
{
a="hidden";
alert(a);
return a;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label class=visible>Hello</label>
<button onclick="doset()">v</button><br>
<label class=a>Hello1</label><br>
<label class=a>Hello2</label><br>
<label class=a>Hello3</label><br>
<label class=a>Hello4</label><br>
<label class=a>Hello5</label><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/M8CXN/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. All you're doing there is overwriting a global variable, not changing an element's class - is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Regarding your html please put quotes around your class names.

Comment: That alerts & returns "hidden" what do you want to do with that value? you should also `onclick="doset(); return false;"` to prevent the page from reloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class=a`

This does **not** bind the class name to the javascript global variable `a`; they are different things in different contexts.

If you want to manipulate classes you must do so via the DOM.  The simplest way is to use a container;

```
<div id="myItems">
   <label>Hello1</label><br>
   <label>Hello2</label><br>
   ...
```

and

```
function doset() {
   a="hidden";
   document.getElementById("myItems").style.visibility = a;   
   alert(a);
}
```

called with

```
<button onclick="doset(); return false;">v</button><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give all the relevant labels the same class:

```
<label class="myclass">Hello1</label><br>
<label class="myclass">Hello2</label><br>
<label class="myclass">Hello3</label><br>
```

You can then target these and add or remove the class you want:

```
$('.myclass').addClass('hidden');
$('.myclass').removeClass('hidden');
```

or just:

```
$('.myclass').hide();
$('.myclass').show();
```

(using [jQuery](http://jquery.com))

Comment: Question wasn't tagged jQuery.

Comment: Nope. It is a pretty useful library for DOM manipulation though :)

Comment: That it is, but if the question is not tagged jQuery you shouldnt give a jQuery answer. Just my $0.02

Comment: @Jamiec not enough jQuery on SO. http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: Damn you, I was looking for that gif to put as a comment here, but couldnt find it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
label.visible {visibility:visible}
label.hidden {visibility:hidden}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function setLabelsClass(){
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    var labels = form[0].getElementsByTagName('label');
    for(var i=0,len=labels.length;i<len;i++){
        var lbl_class = labels[i].getAttribute('class');
        if(lbl_class==="") labels[i].setAttribute('class','hidden');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label class=visible>Hello</label>
<button onclick="setLabelsClass(); return false;">v</button><br>
<label>Hello1</label><br>
<label class="">Hello2</label><br>
<label class="">Hello3</label><br>
<label class="">Hello4</label><br>
<label class="">Hello5</label><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>​
```

Not a good approach after all if you don't provide AJAX since your form doesn't submit anymore.
On second thought I have the feeling you might not understand what I'm talking about here but you'll get to it.